# Can i convert my image to CMY with opencv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a image with `RGB` and i want to convert it into `CMY` . I try to find out it in opencv documentation but i didn't find it [here in cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) , i found its written program but manual converion [here](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/how-to-read-the-digits-from-a-scratchcard/) . Do we have any build in function for it in OpenCv ?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Comment: If the doc doesn't contain anything about it(!) so it does not provide it!